# What does & mean in fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR

Tags: c

I am trying to print the permissions of files in `Linux` using `stat` function call in `C`. And I found some useful code online which has the segments

```
printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
```

The code works perfect, but could anyone explain me what does the `&` mean here?

Comment: It's the bitwise and operator

Comment: Thanks! I am a newbie in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The first line**

`printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");`

This prints an `r` if there are read permissions(S_IRUSR) and a `-` otherwise.

To prevent against a format string attack(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string), you should write:

`printf("%c", (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? 'r' : '-');`

**The second line**

`printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");`

This prints a `w` if there are write permissions(S_IWUSR) and a `-` otherwise.
Again, to prevent format string attacks, you should write:

`printf( "%c", (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? 'w' : '-');`

`&` is the bitwise and operator. In this case, it is used to check if a bitfield is set. A variable `x` could have been set to, say, `A | B | C`. To check if the `C` bit is on, write

```
if (x & C)
    // the bit has been set
```

Comment: You still didn't explained the OP's Question **What does & mean**

Comment: Fixed @Michi [15 characters]

Comment: There is no danger of a "format string attack" with the original version. There are no user-supplied format strings, so there is no danger.

Comment: What if the OP, at some point in the future, decides to modify this code, to print something that might contain a `%`, but forgets that this is vulnerable to format string attacks? Better safe than sorry. @alain

Comment: The problem is not that there is a warning, it's that the answer suggests that this code is vulnerable, and this is not true. It would only be vulnerable if there was a user-supplied string.